# Make element full-width in fixed-width parent

Tags: html, css

Is there a way for an element to become full-width inside of a fixed width parent?

---

So a document with following layout:

```
 _____________________o- body
|   _______________   |
|  |               o------ first
|  |    limited    |  |
|__|_______________|__|
|                     o----- second
|      full-width     |
|_____________________|
|  |               |  |
|  |_______________o------ first
|_____________________|
```

where

```
body > first {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

How can `body > first > second` become full-width?

Comment: you could put `second` outside of `limited` and then change the position to absolute and place it where you want

Comment: @litelite The problem is that I have no idea how big the content of either element will be before

Comment: No matter how big the content is, you can set the full width to be 100%, the content will be adjusted by screen. I agree with litelite, you can make the second div to be absolute, and separate it from limited div.

Comment: @yongwu Even if the width is 100%, how can I account for changing heights?

Comment: well, I couldn't get it. if the content has already been in the div, the height of the div will adjust automatically. if you want to change the position of the div, use top:50%;transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); it will adjust vertically middle. Or you can choose other numbers.